# R tidyverse : Dataset structure format and error when converting from character to numeric

Tags: r, variables, data-structures, dplyr

I think that's a really naive (or dumb) question, but after 4 hours working on this problem, I just gave up. I imported a dataset from google docs to excel (as always) and then to R.

Actually, everything was looking ok, but now I'm facing a strange problem.
When I try to change the format of the variables, it gives me an error and does not continue.

I can count each level I have in the  vector.

```
> db %>% count(x1)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  x1                   n
  <chr>            <int>
1 2 - Raramente        9
2 3 - As vezes        46
3 4 - Quase sempre    71
4 5 - Sempre          16
```

But when I try to transform it to numeric, see what happens:

```
db <- db %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(x1), list(~case_when(
    . == "1 - Nunca" ~ 1,
    . == "2 - Raramente" ~ 2,
    . == "3 - As vezes" ~ 3,
    . == "4 - Quase sempre" ~ 4,
    . == "5 - Sempre" ~ 5,
    TRUE ~ .)))
```

Thats my dataset structure

```
structure(list(x1 = c("4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "5 - Sempre", "5 - Sempre", "3 - As vezes", 
"3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "5 - Sempre", "2 - Raramente", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"3 - As vezes", "5 - Sempre", "5 - Sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "5 - Sempre", "5 - Sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "5 - Sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", 
"3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "2 - Raramente", "2 - Raramente", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "5 - Sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "5 - Sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "5 - Sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", 
"3 - As vezes", "5 - Sempre", "3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"5 - Sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "2 - Raramente", "3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", 
"3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "3 - As vezes", 
"3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "2 - Raramente", "3 - As vezes", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "3 - As vezes", "2 - Raramente", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"3 - As vezes", "5 - Sempre", "3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"2 - Raramente", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "2 - Raramente", 
"3 - As vezes", "5 - Sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"4 - Quase sempre", "5 - Sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", "4 - Quase sempre", 
"3 - As vezes", "4 - Quase sempre", "2 - Raramente")), row.names = c(NA, 
-142L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

For sake of clarity, the real dataset has about 30 variables and I was trying.

Thanks for any help.
By the way: I know that's not the best question when can ask here, but I ask for your comprehension. The reproducible code is above.

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? I get an error `Error: must be a double vector, not a character vector`, but I wouldn't normally call that kind of error a crash.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It displays this error and doesn't proceed. I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every output value in `case_when` needs to have the same type. You're trying to create a `numeric` vector, so you can't have `TRUE ~ .` in `case_when`: `.` is `character`. You can just have the fallback case be `NA`:

```
db %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(x1), list(~case_when(
        . == "1 - Nunca" ~ 1,
        . == "2 - Raramente" ~ 2,
        . == "3 - As vezes" ~ 3,
        . == "4 - Quase sempre" ~ 4,
        . == "5 - Sempre" ~ 5,
        TRUE ~ as.numeric(NA))))
```

(Note that I have `as.numeric(NA)` instead of just `NA` because `case_when()` is so picky about all the output values having the same type).

Comment: `as.numeric(NA)` is `NA_real_` if anybody prefers that.

Comment: Shame on me... this is so embarrassing... It worked very well. After several hours of working, I think my brain was gone. Sorry for asking this really naive question and thank you so much for replying it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `dplyr::recode()`. Much easier:

```
db$x1 <- dplyr::recode(
  db$x1, !!!list(
    "1 - Nunca" = 1,
    "2 - Raramente" = 2,
    "3 - As vezes" = 3,
    "4 - Quase sempre" = 4,
    "5 - Sempre" = 5
  )
)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked as well. Any way to use recode_at ? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have recode_at. But you can:
`db %>% mutate(
    x1 = dplyr::recode(
        .$x1, !!!list(
            "1 - Nunca" = 1,
            "2 - Raramente" = 2,
            "3 - As vezes" = 3,
            "4 - Quase sempre" = 4,
            "5 - Sempre" = 5
        )
    )
)`

Comment: Thank you! I agree with you that recode is easier than mutate, but the lack of _at _all is a downside of the recode.. .

Comment: There's no `recode_at` because `recode` works on individual vectors, while things like `mutate_at` work on dataframes. The way to do this for multiple columns would be to use `mutate_at` and put `recode` in the function/formula for recoding each column.